# WCF client call fails after changing endpoint port

Tags: web-services, wcf, port, load-balancing, alternating

We are facing the following problem. What we have:

1) "Our" ASMX web-services, hosted both on 80 and 8080 ports

2) "Their" unsupported unknown solution which works with our web-services. That is, it is working as is and almost can not be modified. I don't know how it is implemented. It looks like WWF hosted on IIS, but I can't say for sure. But it is 100% .NET solution as ours.

So far this solution calls our services through WCF client proxies using endpoints configured in settings. They are standard WCF-configuration:

[K4 default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgdol.png)

The problem with these endpoints is that they are using default HTTP port 80. We have load balancing, but even round-robin balancing is implemented on port 8080 (so that for port 80 all requests go to 1 specific server but not to 1 random of 3 nodes for every request). So we asked to change endpoint ports in configuraiotn file and test it is working. And this is really working on test server k4-dv.

However when we tried to change ports on production server, everything stopped working. Error that is seen in logs is following:

[Metadata error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avbm0.png)

followed by this:

[HTTP 503 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsUDt.png)

And some other errors, but I can't say whether they are relevant to each other:

[Message contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c34YE.png)

[Timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jIjJ.png)

So my question is fairly obvious: what is the reason of this error and what can be changed, taking in account, that test server works with both ports? What settings should we check?

The main problem is that I don't know reasons of this error and did not manage to find the solution. And there are no people from "their side" who develops this solution. We have only "support" than can check something, change settings, but in this case they can only wait a suggestion from us to fix problem with 8080 port. They don't know reasons either.

Comment: When the port is changed in config file, shouldn't the client proxy also be updated using endpoint wsdl?

Comment: Well, I don't think WSDL depends on ports. Service interface does no change.It just exists as single instance and is accessible through several ports. Moreover I wrote that same changes on test server work. We just changed port from default 80 to 8080 and nothing fails. But on production server it does not work.

Comment: By the way, if I create proxy for some web-service I never recerate it from WSDL for every server where this service is hosted. There is no sense. WSDL does not dened on ports because service interface does not change: same methods, same signatures. So that I create proxy 1 time from WSDL and theh just put appropriate URLs in config files. I.e. I can have 3-4 test servers with different endpotins and ports, but my proxy is generated only once during initial development. Than I just deploy my proxy on some test server and just put correct URL for this specific test server.